# SVG alter path without animation?

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, svg, drawable

I have a battery icon I would like to "animate" as in, change the length of the filling path to indicate battery percentage. However, android documentation for SVG's and SVG animation indicates you can only add predefined animations through xml. Is there a way to just simply alter the path of a SVG and redraw it?

i.e. `SVG.setPath("new path")`?

The only other option I could think of is making separate animations for the "fullness" of the icon (one at 10, 20, 30% etc) but this seems very tedious.

Comment: for this you need to create your custom SVG class

Comment: And how would I proceed with altering the path in my custom class? Assuming we can get the Drawable from an ImageView for example..

Comment: Are you actually using SVGs?  Or do you really mean VectorDrawable?  How are you displaying the battery icon now?

Comment: Imported through the Vector Asset wizard, saved as ic_battery.xml. I can obtain it inside an activity as a Drawable (or VectorDrawable). I know the path and the coordinate I want to edit, so I want to "change the xml" during runtime and then rerender the image. For example, default svg would have path length 0 for battery fullness, then I programatically set it to length 50 for 50% full. For this, I only need to be able to change the path, not necessarily animate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AnimatedSvgView) is the Library you need. Please give it a try. and this is very new library. I have not tried it myself. Please read the readme file or issues of library before using it,.

Comment: This library is not suitable, as I only require altering the path and redrawing it, not animating it.

Comment: for this you have to get the SVG in java

Comment: And how would I do that? I can only obtain access to Drawable or VectorDrawable inside an activity class.

Comment: this is what you can do I have seen a library for this.

Comment: Why dont you simple draw and paint using Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `CustomView` and overwrite `onDraw`. Inside this method, you call `canvas.drawPath` which you pass a `Path` instance. This object should be created in `onCreate` and "filled" with your path data. You need to [understand the SVG/VectorDrawable path](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/understanding-vectordrawable-pathdata-commands-in-android-d56a6054610e) and find the corresponding method of the [`Path`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) class. You also will have to add a scale variable to make it variable in size. In your layout XML you set the size you want.

```
public class CustomView extends View {
    Paint paint;
    Path path;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        path = // construct your path using Path methods
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

For making the battery fill state grow or shrink, you have to add more logic, of course.